# How to get files modified by certain process in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Need to find out files getting modified by certain process.

tried `lsof -p processid`  it gives all files opened by certain process. I just want a command or set of commands to get all files opened and modified by certain process.

Comment: `ls -ltr /proc/pid/fd` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the process is not already running, you can use `strace` to print system calls

```
strace -o logfile  <program>
```

After this, write a script which will look for `open()` and `write()` system calls, and able to print the lists of files which are written too.

If the process is already running, you will have to use the combination of several things

- `lsof -p` or `/proc/<processid>/fd/*`
- last modified time stamp of the files found in above
- output of `strace -p <processid>` to look for `write()` and `open()`

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Use [Auditctl](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) and [Ausearch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch). If it's not installed, install and enable auditing for your distribution.

Set an audit watch on specific /dir  //for Example you can set on /home/user/ or /home/ or whatever you want to audit, in this way:

```
/sbin/auditctl -w /dir -p war -k myaudit

-w watch /dir
-p warx watch for write, attribute change, execute or read events
-k myaudit is a searchkey
```

Then use ausearch to check the log

```
/sbin/ausearch -f /dir
```

In this way you'll get a lot of information. For example from [OpenSuse Documentation](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLES/SLES-security_sd_draft/cha.audit.comp.html#sec.audit.ausearch)

```
ausearch -a 5207
----
time->Tue Feb 17 13:43:58 2009
type=PATH msg=audit(1234874638.599:5207): item=0 name="/var/log/audit/audit.log" inode=1219041 dev=08:06 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00
type=CWD msg=audit(1234874638.599:5207):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1234874638.599:5207): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=4 a0=62fb60 a1=0 a2=31 a3=0 items=1 ppid=25400 pid=25616 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts1 ses=1164 comm="less" exe="/usr/bin/less" key="doc_log"
```

In the output above the tutorial search for a specific event `-a 5207` in the audit daemon log.

In your case you need to get all file modified by specific Pid, then you can use the option of [Ausearch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch)

```
-p, --pid process-id
Search for an event matching the given process ID.
```

And you'll get only the row of the log modified by the specific PID. Remember to define correctly the `-p` attribute for your purpose (only modification).

When you have the informations in log associated to the specified PID, you can extract the filename associated to the event logged.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this is to run the command with strace

Example

```
$ strace ls -l x.pl 2>&1 |grep '"/'
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls", "-l", "x.pl"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
statfs("/selinux", {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=142720486, f_bfree=81207145, f_bavail=73957366, f_files=36249600, f_ffree=34904733, f_fsid={1821263268, 914763317}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_TIME/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

The grep looks for "file path" like items in the very long output